# Analysis on Memory Management

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-dump

I'm doing Memory management analysis for my Java web application,

Before starting my tomcat the free memory in RAM was around 595 MB, Once I started the server the free memory goes to 151 MB. When I took the Heap dump, the objects were occupying 262 MB.

So will tomcat alone take remaining 181 MB?

Another question is, I ran Load Test with 500 Users. The free memory goes to 8MB, When I took heap dump here, It was around 265MB. So free space 151 MB is reduced to 8MB, What could be reason

Please note that I used `top` command to check free memory in RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free memory is the memory not used by the kernel, programs or disk cache.  How big the disk cache is varies based on which files you have accessed or deleted and is a poor indication of memory consumption.

Java uses quite a bit of memory starting up.  Much of it is shared.  Tomcat can be a relatively complex application depending on what you load, but to use 181 MB for the JVM and Tomcat seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Regarding my second question during load test the free memory gets very low, but when I take heap dump I dont see the big differce in size when comparing before Load test and during Load test. what could be the reason for going memory low during load test?

Comment: Did you do the dump during the load test or after the load test?  If you are comparing before and after the test, you would expect it to be much the same unless you have a memory leak.

Comment: The JVM can use more memory than is the amount it would use after a full clean up.  I would use VisualVM to trigger a full GC and see how much it is using just after a clean up.  This will give you a better idea of how much is required and how much is reserved but not live objects.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you compute the free memory (Profiler? TaskManager? Programmatically?) and which memory you are evaluating (Heap? Non-Heap? etc...) Tomcat on its own does not take much memory (I don't recall exactly, but a basic setup should definitely not take 180Mb)

Comment: ok, this is probably not the best approach to compute the actual memory taken. But more importantly, the heap is a "growing" memory:it starts with a minimum amount of memory and then each time it needs more memory than currently available, it increases its allocated memory (until it reaches a maximum). This means that your object may take 100Mb but the heap may use 128Mb. There you have 28Mb unused. You should probably read more about Java memory and Java GC.